# I want to reference an img's alt text using event handlers. How do I reference the img tag in a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

[image]

Let's say I want to display the alt text for creek. How do I use the html DOM alt attribute in a function to target that specific image

Answer (score 1):

You can just access it by its property

```
var altText = cr.alt
```

Heres some reference https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_alt.asp

Answer (score 0):

to check image alt:  `cr.alt`
to return it: `alert(cr.alt)`
to change image alt: `cr.alt = 'your new alt';`